# Perl, Decoding bits stored in a binary file

Tags: perl, binary, bit-manipulation

I'm decoding a fixed-width binary file in perl. One of the fields is 1 byte in length and the 8 bits are encoded such that:

> The 7th Bit unused, The 0-4th bit is used to indicate Field1. The 5-6th Bit is used to indicate Field2.

For example the field `0x27` will give Field1 = `7`, Field2 = `1`.

I'm reading all the fields into a hash table called `raw{}` and then decoding the values into another hash called `processed{}`.

The code (only shown for this one byte) is

```
while (read(FILE, $buff, 559)) {
  %raw = ();            # Hash for first-pass extractions
  %processed = ();      # Hash for cleaned up values, for output

  (
    ......
    $raw{'Field12'},
    ......
  )= unpack('
             .....
             H2
             .....
             h*',$buff);

$prcoessed{'Field1'} = unpack("B8", pack("H8", $raw{'Field12'})) & 0x1f;
$prcoessed{'Field2'} = (unpack("B8", pack("H8", $raw{'Field12'})) >> 5) & 0x3;
```

However, I don't get the desired values. I get `$prcoessed{'Field1'} = 15` and `$prcoessed{'Field2'} = 3`. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Your first description of the fields has incorrectly switched Field1 and Field2, making the rest of the question slightly confusing.

Comment: @aecolley Yes. Corrected it now :).

Answer (score 1):

`0x1f` is a number, you need to transform it into a character.

Instead of packs and unpacks, you can use [`ord`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ord.html) and [`chr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chr.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $char = chr 0x27;

my $field1 = $char & chr 0x1f;

my $field2 = $char & chr 0x60;
$field2 = chr(ord($field2) >> 5);

print ord, "\n" for $field1, $field2;
```

The same script using [`pack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) and [`unpack`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html):

```
my $char = pack 'C', 0x27;

my $field1 = $char & pack 'C', 0x1f;

my $field2 = $char & pack 'C', 0x60;
$field2 = pack 'C', unpack('C', $field2) >> 5;

print unpack('C', $_), "\n" for $field1, $field2;
```